# Display document in UIWebView with proper format (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, doc

I am opening a word document file in `UIWebView`.

It works perfect but the problem is that when I open that doc file it does not display in proper format like in word.

**In UIWebView :**

[image: This is the problem all text are display in center]

**Code :**

```
let url = NSURL(string: self.docUrl.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
    webView.delegate = self
    webView.scalesPageToFit = true // I have also try by removing this statement
    webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have scales pages to fit, it looks like you might not have constraints setup correctly.

You will need to create constraints between your UIWebView and its parent to ensure that the webView takes over the whole screen.

You can create constraints both in storyboard as well as in code.

Comment: I have already set the frame of `UIWebView` to `view`'s frame.

Comment: Open the same link in Safari if you can and see what behavior you get. It could be a problem with the site hosting the .doc that can cause this issue. If safari displays the document the same way , then there isn't much you can do about it without hacking ( set zoom level to more than 100% )